# What type of data are returned by the X() and Y() MySql functions that take a point field as parameter

Tags: mysql, database, geospatial, rdbms, mysql-spatial

I am not so into database. Into a geospatial query I have something like this:

```
SELECT X(gps) AS longitude, Y(gps) AS latitude FROM MyTable
```

Where the **gps** field hve **point** as type.

And it returnes value like:

```
29,3715    -2,1790
```

My doubt is: what is the exact type of data returned by the previous **X()** and **Y()** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of MySQL function [`X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_x) explains:

> [`ST_X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-x) and [`X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_x) are synonyms. For more information, see the description of [`ST_X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-x).
>
> [`X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_x) is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release.
> Use [`ST_X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-x) instead.

The documentation of [`ST_X()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-x) says:

> `ST_X(P)`
>
> Returns the X-coordinate value for the `Point` object `p` as a double-precision number.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `double-precision number`

Here's the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-point-property-functions.html), note that these functions are alias for `st_x` and `st_y` and are due for depreciation.

Regards,

James